# How to get break in and out time sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table data

```
        id EVENTID       DT
        1   1   2018-06-21 16:00:00.000
        1   4   2018-06-21 14:00:00.000
        1   3   2018-06-21 13:00:00.000
        1   4   2018-06-21 11:00:00.000
        1   3   2018-06-21 10:00:00.000
        1   0   2018-06-21 08:17:12.000
```

Eventid:
0 as in
1 as out
3 as breakout
4 as breakin

Below query i used but not able to get all break times in same row

```
select
    t.emp_reader_id as empId,B.emp_name, cast(max(DT) as date) as Belongs_to,B.areaname as POINTID, max(iif(EVENTID = 0, DT, null)) as EntryTime, max(iif(EVENTID = 1, DT, null)) as ExitTime,
     max(iif(EVENTID = 3, DT, null)) as Breakin, max(iif(EVENTID = 4, DT, null)) as Breakout,
      format(dateadd(ss,Datediff(second,max(iif(EVENTID = 0, DT, null)),max(iif(EVENTID = 1, DT, null))),0),'HH:mm') as Worked
      ,CONVERT( CHAR(11), @Date_From, 103 ) as StartDate
      ,CONVERT( CHAR(11), @Date_To, 103 ) as ToDate
from (  
    select
        *, grp =sum(iif(EVENTID = 1,0, 0) ) over (partition by emp_reader_id order by DT) ,
        grp1 =   sum(iif(EVENTID = 3,4, 0) )over (partition by emp_reader_id order by DT)
    from
        Trnevents
) t inner join employee B on t.emp_reader_id=B.emp_reader_id
   group by t.emp_reader_id,t.grp,B.emp_name,t.Belongs_to,B.areaname
```

Expected Output:

```
  empId emp_name    Belongs_to  POINTID        EntryTime          ExitTime        Breakout1             Breakout1             Breakout2         Breakout2  Worked     StartDate     ToDate
    1         ***      2018-06-21     ***   2018-06-21 08:17:12     2018-06-21 16:00:00 2018-06-21 11:00:00 2018-06-21 13:00:00 2018-06-21 13:00:00 2018-06-21 14:00:00 05:42   2018-06-21  2018-06-21
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: how many breakouts/breakins can there be in one day?

Comment: Could someone have 3 breaks? Maybe 4, 5, more?

Comment: 2 or may be more depend upon punch

Comment: If it's an indeterminate amount, then the only solution is using dynamic SQL. Personally, I would pivot your data in your presentation layer. It's generally easier.

Comment: max 2 break in /out is enough

Comment: Well, which is it? *"2 or may be more depend upon punch"* and *"max 2 break in /out is enough"* contradict each other.

Comment: 2 break in/out punch

Comment: to confirm, breakin/out can be 0, 1 or 2 for each shift?

Answer (score -1):

As you have suggested that you are having limited breakouts this would work just follow the sequence till the end.

I look at this in a way what if multiple id have different number of breaks so it may lead you to dynamic sql..

```
SELECT id AS empid, convert(varchar , stbstr(tt, 1, 10) , 2) AS Belongs_to, 
convert(varchar ,stbstr(TT, instr(TT, '$1', 1), instr(TT, '$1', 1)+23) , 2) AS EntryTime,...
FROM (
SELECT id, string_agg(dt + '$' + cast(EventID AS VARCHAR) + DT , ',') AS TT
FROM time_table
GROUP BY id
)
```

Comment: string_agg only available in 2016 and OP hasn't stated Version

Comment: ohk then go with xml one